# windows 10 and Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, windows-10

I see that there are a few questions regarding win 10. Has anyone encountered problems running AS 1.3.1 under Win 10? My experience is frequent lock-up/reboot of my pc. Also, Genymotion does not work at all. I've downgraded to Win 7 and now all is ok again.

Answer (score 0):

What are the problems that are occurring?  I have Android Studio up and running fine on my Windows 10.  Nexus 6 emulator working, HAXM installed et al.  Please list specific problems you are having and lets see what's up.

Healy in Tampa